# Can't add new nodes to TreeView control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I want to add a node from one form to the other one. I have the following code, but it does not work:

From Form2:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _HauptFenster = new Form1();
    _HauptFenster.AddGroup(textBox1.Text);
    this.Close();   
}
```

to Form1:

```
public void AddGroup(string name)
{
    MessageBox.Show(name);
    Einträge.Nodes.Add(name);
}
```

I can see the real name of the node in the MessageBox, but the node is not being added to the TreeView on Form1.

Comment: Mein Deutsch ist nicht so gut, but I'm assuming Eintrage is your TreeView. I don't have VS pulled up right now but cannot really trouble shoot but I think the Add method takes a Node as a parameter. Can you maybe try Eintage.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(name)); ?

Comment: hey Shaman, thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunately adding a new TreeNode is not the solution. I can see the correct name in my messagebox, but the treeview will not add the node. If i´m adding a new node directly from Form1, it will work.

Comment: Do you have an instance of Form1 open at the time which button2 is clicked? Each time you click button2 you are creating a new instance of Form1 and calling the AddGroup function but you never display the newly created form. If you add _HauptFenster.Show() before this.Close()  it will show the newly created form. I'm guessing you aren't meaning to create a new instance of Form1 everytime but want the entered text to be displayed in a TreeView on an existing form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible scenarios:

1. You have a Form2 and you need to add a node to Form1's treeview (assuming Form1 has already shown). In that case, you can't use  `_HauptFenster = new Form1();` which is a new Form1, not the one you already have. What you should do is to make a reference of form1 in form2:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       Form1 form1;

       public Form2()
       {    
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public Form2(Form1 form1):this()
       {
           this.form1= form1;
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           form1.AddGroup("something");
           this.Close();
       }
   }
   ```

   and change modify the way you open Form2:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form2 form2= new Form2(this);
       form2.Show();
   }
   ```
2. Form1 has not been shown yet, because you forgot to bring it up:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form1 form1= new Form1 ();
       form1.Show();
       form1.AddGroup("something");
       this.Close();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
Form1 master = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
master.Einträge.Nodes.Add(name);
```

I think this is what [ShAkKiR said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33722981/366904); specifically, scenario 1, where I was trying to add it to a TreeView control in a *new* instance of Form1, instead of adding to to the *existing* instance of Form1.

Comment: Yes, that works too. Instead of declaring the form as a new instance you wanted to grab the instance that was already open.